# Heroku is not running my bot discord.js and causing errors

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I keep getting this error everytime heroku runs my bot:

```
2020-08-31T14:55:51.202566+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-08-31T14:55:51.221755+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-08-31T14:55:51.282351+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-08-31T14:55:51.317667+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Here is My ProcFile:

```
worker: node index.js
```

My Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "yuuto-giveaway",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Giveaway Bot",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.3.1",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "ms": "^2.1.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Fun"
  ],
  "author": "BlueFire",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I do not know how to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

```
2020-08-31T14:55:51.202566+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

This is Heroku's error in their program, this is not your fault. Try recreating it, reuploading it, or change hosts from Heroku. Try [Glitch](http://glitch.com), it works just fine for a free host. Though I suggest that you shouldn't use free hosts like Heroku and [Glitch](http://glitch.com) because they're [extremely] unreliable.